# dynamically add boostrap rows and columns in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, linq, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with my foreach loop:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 3)
{
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model) 
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UrlSlug)">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UrlSlug)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
                </h3>
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDescription)</p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

This method displays one big long list, however I only want to display three (3x) `<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">` inside `<div class="row">` after three portfolio items has been populated I then want to create another `<div class="row">` and populate the **next** three `<div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use an outer for loop like `for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i += 3)` than the `<div class="row">` and your actual foreach uses `Model.Skip(i).Take(3)`.

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 3)
{
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model.Skip(i).Take(3)) 
        {
            <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item">
                <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UrlSlug)">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                <a href="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UrlSlug)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</a>
                </h3>
                <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShortDescription)</p>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: @GarrithGraham What is the type of `Model`?

Comment: I forgot the `@` in the first line and amended `.Count` to `.Count()` as IEnumerable does not have that property. You will also need to import LINQ with `@using System.Linq` at the top of your view.

Comment: Damn it, I wanted to declare `i` before and then realized that I only forgot the `@`. It should work now!